# How to join tables in SQL Server by date Valid_from/Valid_to

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How to join the tables at image in SQL Server by date Valid_from/Valid_to

[image: Pic output]

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand English language.

Comment: But. I want to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put your queries in text, not images. You can use JOINS to achieve this or you can do like this

```
SELECT A.ID, A.DATE,A.AMOUNT, B.NAME
FROM test_T_cust A 
     INNER JOIN test_M_cust B
     ON A.ID=B.ID AND
A.DATE BETWEEN B.V_FROM AND B.V_TO;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: I agree! I have mentioned about JOINS in my answer. @jarlh

Comment: Edited my answer :), I am not a fan of old-style JOIN. But my manager is not used to modern joins. So am forced to use old -style :( @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

Using simple SQL query, you can try joining two tables.

Check the below code :

```
SELECT 
  test_T_cust.ID, test_T_cust.Date, test_T_cust.Amount, test_M_cust.Name 
FROM
  test_T_cust

LEFT JOIN
  test_M_cust
ON 
  test_T_cust.Date >= test_M_cust.V_From AND test_T_cust.Date <= test_M_cust.V_To
```